# Index out of bounds for Length and not sorting correctly

Tags: java, selection-sort

I am working on a selection sort algorithm and I'm running into a problem. Sometimes it sorts correctly, sometimes it doesn't. And I constantly run into the error "Index _ out of bounds for length _"
I'm completely stumped. Any advice? Work done in Java

```
public class Selection{
   System.out.println("Please input a value for N");
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int n = input.nextInt();
   int[] array = new int[n];

   for (int i =0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please input a value for index" + i);
        int element = input.nextInt();
        array[i] = element;
    }
    select(array);
 }

public static void select(int[] sorter) {
    for (int i = 0; i< sorter.length; i++) {
    int k = sorter[i];
    int lowest_number = sorter[i + 1];
    for (int j = i; j < sorter.length; j++) {
         if (sorter[j] > -1){
             lowest_number = j;
         }
     }
     int intermediate = sorter[i];
     sorter[i] = sorter[lowest_number};
     sorter[lowest_number] = intermediate;
     System.out.println("----------");
     printarray(sorter);
    }
 }
public static void printarray(int[] print) {
     for (int i = 0; i < [rint.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(print[i]);
     }
}
```

}

Comment: `int lowest_number = sorter[i + 1]` will get OOB for `array.length+1`. So if length is for example 5 and you reach 4th iteration i.e i = 4 then above line will make it 5 with addition of 1 and upper bound in above example is 4 (0..4)

Answer (score 0):

Your IndexOutOfBoundsException is caused by this code:

```java
int lowest_number = sorter[i + 1];
```

which gets index `i + 1` from `sorter`, which is one too much in case that `i` is `sorter.length - 1`.
Another issue is that `lowest_number` is being set to the last non-negative value index in `sorter`, rather than to the lowest value index.

This should give you a good indication on what to work on without giving away a full working insertion sort algorithm right away, as practise seems to be the goal here.